# Source problem for children page image

Tags: post-thumbnails, timthumb

I have this problem and maybe you can help me.
I want to get a list of all children pages from page (with id 20) and then get the featured image from each one and resize with Thumbnail. Right now I get the_title from each one but not the Image so think there is a source problem. here's the code:

```
    <?php $args = array (
                    'child_of'     => 20,
                    'title_li'     => '',
                    'depth'         => 0,
                    'sort_order'    => 'DESC',
                    'sort_column'   => 'menu_order'
                    );

                    $pages = get_pages( $args );
                    foreach($pages as $page)  :
    setup_postdata($post);

    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), false, '' ); 
    $thumbnailSrc = $src[0];    
    ?>
    <li id="<?php echo $page->post_name; ?>">
    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h2>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumbnailSrc; ?>&h=256&w=415&zc=1q=100" />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </li>
```

Comment: why do you want to resize the image instead of making a default thumb size? that way you can create a single loop why a query that will achieve your results... let me know your reason so I'll see if I can help u

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As this is used on a template file which is no parent page from page id 20 I get nothing from
`<?php echo $thumbnailSrc; ?>` What I want is to get the resized images from page with id 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind about my question... here is your answer

Put this function on your functions.php

```
 // Get Featured Image Path
 function get_featured_image_link($size){
  global $post;
  $get_featured_image_link = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $size);
  preg_match("/(?<=src=['|\"])[^'|\"]*?(?=['|\"])/i", $get_featured_image_link, $thePath);
  return $get_featured_image_link_final = $thePath[0];
 }
```

Then this is the process to get the image...

```
 <?php
  $the_query = new  WP_Query( 
      array(
          'post_parent' => '20',
          'post_type' => 'page',
          'sort_column'   => 'menu_order'
      )
  ); ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li id="<?php echo $page->post_name; ?>">
     <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
     <img src="<?php echo get_featured_image_link('Path'); ?>">
   </li> 
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query() ?>
```

Set the width and height to whatever you want to...

Tested and worked!

Have fun!

Comment: hooooowever...I still don't know why you want to resize it instead of defining a specific thumbnail size and call it with the <?php the_thumbnail('YOURCUSTOMSIZE') ?> function :)!

Comment: Wow! this works great!

Reagrding the_thumbnail: Never managed to make it work as wanted, always have some issues with landscape and vertical format images, never crop the same size.

Thanks for your help!